# Android room shows the error AppDatabase_Impl does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am developing an app and add the room for database but it shows the error is

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.app.android/com.app.android.activities.AttendanceActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for
>   com.app.android.db.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist

In gradle file I have add every thing. My gradle file is shown below. I don't know. what is the problem. This code is working in another application. But it shows in this application. Kindly help me.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.app.android'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 16
//     edumia   versionCode 16
    versionName "2.0.5"
//       edumia  versionName "2.0.5"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}
repositories {
jcenter()
maven {
    url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
}
maven {
    url 'https://dl.bintray.com/ayz4sci/maven/'
}

}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
compile 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.3.0'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.3.0'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'
compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.11'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:1.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.ayz4sci.androidfactory:downloadprogress:1.0.2'
compile('com.alibaba.android:ultraviewpager:1.0.6@aar') {
    transitive = true
}


compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-rc1';
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-rc1';
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-rc1';
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-rc1';
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class AttendanceActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Class_ class_;
    private AppDatabase database;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            database = AppDatabase.getDatabase(getApplicationContext());
            database.classDao().removeAllUsers();

            Class_ aClass = new Class_(1,"model");
            database.classDao().addClass(aClass);

            Log.d(TAG, "added success");

}
```

**AppDatabase.java**

```
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase{

private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;
public abstract ClassDao classDao();
public static AppDatabase getDatabase(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
       INSTANCE =
                Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "edumiadatabase")
//Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class)
                        // To simplify the exercise, allow queries on the main thread.
                        // Don't do this on a real app!
                        .allowMainThreadQueries()
                        // recreate the database if necessary
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build();


    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public static void destroyInstance() {
    INSTANCE = null;
}
}
```

**Class_.java**

```
public class Class_ {
@PrimaryKey
public int id;
public String Class_;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getClass_() {
    return Class_;
}

public void setClass_(String class_) {
    Class_ = class_;
}

public Class_(int id, String class_){
    this.id=id;
    this.Class_ = class_;
}
}
```

**ClassDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface ClassDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void addClass(Class_ user);

    @Query("delete from user")
    void removeAllUsers();

}
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `@Database` annotation for your database class, and `@Entity` for your entity. See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Comment: I have add `@Database` and `@Entity` but it shows another error.

Comment: Ok? What is the new error? Those annotations are required for Room to work, the new error means that you now get a little further.
As a wild guess I'd assume it complains about `delete from user` as there is no such table (your entity will produce a table called `class_`).
I'd also note that Room 1.0.0 has been released, so there is no reason to keep using rc1.

Comment: Error:(8, 8) error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
Class_(int,java.lang.String) : [id : id, class_ : null]

Comment: Your entity constructor has a parameter called `class_` while the field it sets is called `Class_`, those two need to have the same name (case sensitive).

Comment: Your answer is correct the problem solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have added `@Database(entities = {Class_.class}, version = 1)` in AppDatabase.java .  The @Database annotation for your database class, and @Entity for your entity. I have given as correct. Then the issue solved.

Comment: Your answer isn't really clear. Can you please write it again properly.

Comment: Since this comment isn't exactly clear, here is the appropriate reference in the Android Room documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room (Section: **AppDatabase**)

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem even after adding correct dependency in my

`build.gradle` of my **app** module. My problem was ,I have used different module for separating database layer and **I have moved my dependency to `build.gradle` of corresponding module solved my problem**.

Hope this will helpful to someone else !!!

Answer (score 0):

@Database annotation is missing

add annotation something like this

```
@Database(entities = [Articles::class], version = 1)
abstract class NewsDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun articlesDao(): ArticlesDao
}
```

also for kotlin add following line to dependencies

```
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

also i was using kotlin and all my data class members were non nullable.
worked fine after i changed them to nullable types